# How to add animation for a dynamic text area

Tags: javascript, css

I tried to add some animation to a dynamic text area, but it doesn't work. Can anyone tell how to fix it?
here is my scenario. Initially I want to see a text area with some rows (let's take 3 rows) and after when I started to write in that it should grow up, let's say from another line..like that I need to expand that area whenever I go to a new line. just like that, when I delete some lines there, the height of text area should be reduced too. In my code snippet, those are working properly but without animations. I need to add the same animation for the expanding and collapsing parts.

Here is the code:

```js
function textAreaAdjust(element) {
  element.style.height = "auto";
  element.style.height = (25 + element.scrollHeight) + "px";
}
```

```css
textarea {
  -webkit-transition: height 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: height 0.2s ease;
  transition: height 0.2s ease;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="text" rows="3" onkeyup="textAreaAdjust(this)"
          style="overflow:hidden"></textarea>
```

Comment: You need to set a default height from the css to get it to work

Comment: What is your goal here? To grow the `textarea` as a user types? Or just once when they start typing?

Comment: @DarrenSweeney - here is my scenario. Initially I want to see a text area with 3 rows. and after when I started to write in that it should grow up, let's say from another line..like that I need to expand that area whenever I go to a new line. just like that, when I delete some lines there, the height of text area should be reduced too. In my code snippet, those are working properly but without animations. I need to add the same animation for the expanding and collapsing parts.

Answer (score 2):

You can't transition from `height: auto`. You can assign height based on the rendered height (using `scrollHeight` since you're using that to calculate the height you want to transition to), then add 25 to it and transition to that.

```js
var sized = false;
function textAreaAdjust(element) {
  if (!sized) {
    element.style.height = element.scrollHeight + "px";
    element.style.height = 25 + element.scrollHeight + "px";
    sized = true;
  }
}
```

```css
textarea {
  -webkit-transition: height 0.2s ease;
 -moz-transition: height 0.2s ease;
 transition: height 0.2s ease;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="text" rows="3" onkeyup="textAreaAdjust(this)" style="overflow:hidden"></textarea>
```

Comment: Good start, except you need to check if you need to increase the height instead of adding on every keyup. OP can probably get it working from there though.

Comment: @JacqueGoupil ah good call, only tested with a single character :) Added a simple way to keep it from growing to infinity.

Comment: thank you Michael. But I want that transition when I type multiple lines. and when I delete some lines, that height of text area should be decreased with the same animation.

Comment: @GayathreeKaluarachchi that wasn't clear from your original post. Be sure to ask clear questions so we don't waste one another's time with things you aren't looking for.

Comment: @MichaelCoker I am really sorry for that michael and I edited my question again. Thank you very much for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

**Try using jquery .css**

Try out my code below.

```js
$(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#text").css("height", "300");
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
textarea {
  -webkit-transition: height 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: height 0.2s ease;
  transition: height 0.2s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="text" style="overflow:hidden; width:300px; height:200px; border:1px black dashed"></textarea>
```

Comment: When adding a code snippet there's a wonderful button named "tidy", try it out...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a build off of [Michael Coker's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43900280/4760460). Check if the `scrollHeight` is greater than the `offsetHeight`.

```js
function textAreaAdjust(element) {
  if (element.scrollHeight > element.offsetHeight) {
   element.style.height = (25 + element.scrollHeight)+"px";
  }
}
```

```css
textarea {
  height: 20px;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.2s ease;
 -moz-transition: height 0.2s ease;
 transition: height 0.2s ease;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="text" rows="3" onkeyup="textAreaAdjust(this)" style="overflow:hidden"></textarea>
```

**UPDATE**

I think the easiest way to accomplish what you want is to create a `contenteditable` `div` inside of a `div` that is styled to look like a `textarea`.

```js
function textAreaAdjust(element) {
 // increase height by 25 of #textarea div (parent element to #text div) if #textarea scrollHeight is greater than offsetHeight
  if (element.parentElement.scrollHeight > element.parentElement.offsetHeight) {
   element.parentElement.style.height = (25 + element.parentElement.scrollHeight)+"px";
  }
  // decrease height by 25 of #textarea div if #textarea scrollHeight is greater than scrollHeight+25 of #text div
  if (element.parentElement.scrollHeight > element.scrollHeight + 25) {
   element.parentElement.style.height = (element.scrollHeight)+"px";
  }
}
```

```css
#textarea {
  width: 180px;
  background: #FFF;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  height: 20px;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.2s ease;
 -moz-transition: height 0.2s ease;
 transition: height 0.2s ease;
}

#text:focus {
  outline: 0px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="textarea">
  <div id="text" onkeyup="textAreaAdjust(this)" contenteditable="true"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you anthony. And I want to reduce the height of the text area when I'm deleting some lines with the same transition too. can you help with that too?

Comment: I've updated the code. Also, this is just a start, you'll probably want to see if the user is pasting (`onpaste event`) or cutting (`oncut event`) text in the `contenteditable` `div`.